# What is the difference between Pantheon DROPS and vanilla Drupal?

Tags: 7

Is it just the added config wrappers, or is the Drupal site code itself changed? Are there any changes to Drupal module and filesystem compatibility compared to a more traditional Drupal hosting environment?

Answer (score 10):

Pantheon's variant of Drupal is openly hosted on GitHub:

https://github.com/pantheon-systems/drops-7

The main variation that matters is in `drupal_settings_initialize()`:

https://github.com/pantheon-systems/drops-7/blob/master/includes/bootstrap.inc#L720

This is how Pantheon runs sites without making users handle DB or Redis credentials. This change is now in Pressflow as well.

The other material addition is an apachesolr integration package and a way for the site to query the Pantheon API. Those are in modules/pantheon.

The good news is none of this will prevent a site from working anywhere else. The changes are all designed to revert to normal when not on Pantheon.

Comment: pantheon_apachesolr won't allow a local or third-party hosted site to access a Pantheon Apache Solr core; it'll only work when the site is on Pantheon.

Comment: at one point, functions dealing with their Valhalla FS were "in house" and not up on GitHub, eg, `pantheon_cache()` and `pantheon_stat()`, but were also appropriated wrapped so as to not WSOD if they weren't defined on another platform.

Comment: @Jimajamma - true; we've actually worked to remove the need for these custom functions as we've made Valhalla more and more powerful and performant. `pantheon_stat()` and the other tweaks we did to image generation are a thing of the past.